# How to override css in Django Admin?

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I want to change certain css in admin django like `base.css`. Is it better to change directly in the django library? How can I override it in the best way?

Answer (score 134):

It depends a lot of what you want to do. Though first of all: do not overwrite it in the Django admin directly. You got two options I think are reasonable:

1. If you want to change the appearance of the admin in general you should override admin templates. This is covered in details here: [Overriding admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). Sometimes you can just extend the original admin file and then overwrite a block like `{% block extrastyle %}{% endblock %}` in `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html` as an example.
2. If your style is model specific you can add additional styles via the `Media` meta class in your `admin.py`. See an example here:

> ```
> class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
>     class Media:
>         js = ('js/admin/my_own_admin.js',)    
>         css = {
>              'all': ('css/admin/my_own_admin.css',)
>         }
> ```

Comment: Actually, it's not model level but the whole site itself. To be specific changes in base.css,ie.css etc. One option is to include the admin/base.html in my application itself and use my custom base.css in the admin/base.html file. That way I will have to include some template files from the django admin to my own site. Is there any better solution than this ?

Comment: None I am aware of. The django admin is in the end nothing else than a django reusable app. That's the way to go with any other reusable app as well.

Comment: I notice there's a .css file listed within the js here... does that actually work?  I can't get it to.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a mistake and edited my answer with an example from the django docs.

Comment: In the words of Eli Porter, "You grilled the best cat".

Comment: @Gabriel I can not answer you that. Wagtail wasn't around when I wrote this answer and I haven't used it yet. The django admin uses some special handling here, which Wagtail might not implement the same way.

Comment: @TorstenEngelbrecht Yesss, i am use with Wagtail and is work!

Answer (score 59):

- In `settings.py`, make sure your app is listed before admin in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.
- Create `(your-app)/templates/admin/base_site.html` and put the `<style>` block into the `{% block extrahead %}`

---

Example:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <style>
        .field-__str__ {
            font-family: Consolas, monospace;
        }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Best answer. If you want you can also avoid to list your app before admin in INSTALLED_APPS by putting a "template" directory in base project and referencing it in settings.py:
TEMPLATES = [
...other stuffs...,
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
]

Comment: Great idea! Works smoothly like a charm!

Comment: If you use a custom authentication user model and want to unregister the authentication group model in admin.py, make sure to list django.contrib.auth before your app.

Answer (score 35):

This solution will work for the admin site, I think it's the cleanest way because it overrides `base_site.html` which doesn't change when upgrading django.

Create in your templates directory a folder called `admin` in it create a file named `base_site.html`.

Create in your static directory under `css` a file called `admin-extra.css` .

Write in it all the custom css you want for your forms like: `body{background: #000;}`.

Paste this in the `base_site.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static from staticfiles %} # This might be just {% load static %} in your ENV

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/admin-extra.css" %}" />{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

As mentioned in the comments:
make sure your app is before the admin app in INSTALLED_APPS, otherwise your template doesn't override django's

That's It! you're done

Comment: Thanks, works great! If it doesn't work, make sure your app is before the admin app in `INSTALLED_APPS`, otherwise your template doesn't override django's.

Comment: Best answer and comment. It is surprisingly difficult to change the coloring on the admin page. Going through this answer and comment did solidify how it works.

Comment: How do you know that `base_site.html` will never change when upgrading django? (I mean yes this answer is 3 years old and still works but that's no garantuee)

Comment: @marv if you look under the hood in the source code you can see very easily the admin architecture is built around these specific names especially in the urls and the template rendering. classes that inherit classes that inherit classes rely on these names staying the same unless there will be a major redesign of the Django framework   (and even then I wouldn't bet on this changing) the overall basic convention of overriding admin views and admin urls as well as overriding the base template will stay the same for the next 3 years at the least according to django roadmap.

Comment: So this is just general knowledge about django and there is no concrete source confirming this? It's not that i doubt you, I just wonder how one is supposed to find out that this is the case.

Comment: I love knowledge and doubts (hence the +1 for your comments). there is an official road map for each django version as well as issues and tickets which are "good to have". I haven't found any mentions of this being changed/revisited or even complaints regarding the admin url/view/templating naming convention. Everything is open source and you can look it up for yourself.

Comment: some times all you need is to clear your browser cache

Answer (score 29):

I just extended admin/base.html to include a reference to my own css file - at the end. The beauty of css is that you don't have to touch existing definitions, just re-define.

Answer (score 19):

In your static directory, create a `static/admin/css/base.css` file.

Paste in [Django's default Admin CSS](https://raw.github.com/django/django/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css) first, then add your customizations at the bottom.

Comment: If you do this, be sure to put your app BEFORE `django.contrib.admin` in the list of `INSTALLED_APPS`.   If you don't, collectstatic will find the admin base.css first and your customized version won't overwrite it.

Comment: This isn't a good long term solution. It copy/pastes a bunch of code and it won't be maintained as Django upgrades.

Comment: Any styling to the Django admin is basically a fork of the code. An update to Django could in effect break your customizations. My recommendation is to keep customizations to a minimum and add them at the bottom of Django's default styling. Then you can manually update the default styling if and when you want to.

Comment: @danny-w-adair's answer above is better; keeps things "DRY", but it's still a fork of Django's code that could lead to minor upgrade pains.

Answer (score 14):

If you want a global scope and you don't want to think about overriding templates a mixin works really well for this. Put this code wherever you want:

```
class CSSAdminMixin(object):
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('css/admin.css',),
        }
```

Then, make a CSS file called `admin.css` with your overrides, for example:

```
select[multiple] {
    resize: vertical;
}
```

Then, in whatever models you want, do:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, CSSAdminMixin):
```

And you'll be all set.

Comment: I like your answer, but why not to add directly to MyModelAdmin

Comment: You could do that if it's one model, but it'll get messy if you do it to many models.

Answer (score 5):

Have `admin/css/changelists.css` inside a folder in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, and it will user that changelists.css instead of the default admin one.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `base.css` in Django Admin.

For example, there is `Person` model as shown below:

```py
# "app1/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, there is `Person` admin as shown below:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, there is `Person` admin as shown below:

[image]

Then, copy [base.css](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css) from `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css` in your virtual environment to `static/admin/app1/css/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 |-app2
 └-static
    └-admin
       └-app1
          └-css
             └-base.css # Here
```

Then in `base.css`, replace `background: var(--header-bg);` with `background: black;` as shown below to change the header color to black in `Person` admin page:

```css
/* "static/admin/app1/css/base.css" */

#header {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    /* background: var(--header-bg); */
    background: black;
    color: var(--header-color);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

First, I explain how to change the header color to black in `Person` admin page.

So, set `"admin/app1/css/base.css"` to `css` in [Media class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/media/#assets-as-a-static-definition) as shown below:

```py
# "app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {    # ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
            "all": ("admin/app1/css/base.css",)
        }
```

Then, the header color is changed to black in `Person` admin page as shown below:

[image]

And, the header color is not changed to black in `Animal` admin as shown below:

[image]

Next, I explain how to change the header color to black in all admin pages.

So, copy [base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) from `/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html` in your virtual environment to `/templates/admin/base.html` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  └-admin.py
 |-app2
 |-static
 |  └-admin
 |     └-app1
 |        └-css
 |           └-base.css # Here
 └-templates
    └-admin
       └-base.html # Here
```

Then in `base.html`, replace `admin/css/base.css` with `admin/app1/css/base.css` in [{% static %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#static):

```
# "templates/admin/base.html"

# ...
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
{# <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}"> #}
{# ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ #}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "admin/app1/css/base.css" %}"> {# ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ #}
{% block dark-mode-vars %}
#...
```

Then, the header color is changed to black in `Person` and `Animal` admins as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It just so happens that using `<style>` tag inside `{% block extrastyle %}{% endblock %}` did not work for me when I wanted to override css. [Theming support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#theming-support) provides the correct way. All I was missing is `{{ block.super }}` :-

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}
<style>
--- your style ---
--- properties here ---
</style>
{% endblock %}
```