# Django admin colours

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

The Django Admin page is different shades of blue by default.
Where do I access how these colours are controlled? I want to change it all to shades of green instead of blue.

Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can override the admin templates. You probably want to the `admin/base_site.html` template, and provide an `extrastyle` block with any CSS you want to inject into the template. You'll need to know which styles to override (there's quite a few) - when I did this I just found the elements I wanted to change, and added styles until everything looked right.

So, presuming you've got a templates directory somewhere (which is set in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`), create a file called `admin/base_site.html`, which is probably going to be a copy of `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html`.

For example, my `base_site.html` template has a section in it like this:

```
{% block extrastyle %}
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/adminextra.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
{% endblock %}
```

In `yourcssfile.css` you just have:

```
a:link, a:visited { color: awesome; text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: Would you mind a quick example? I'm not sure I'm catching on.. Say I want to overwrite this bit: a:link, a:visited {
    color: #5b80b2;
    text-decoration: none;
}   How would you do that?

Comment: You create a custom css file like Dominic described and then you put the above css classes in that file that you modify to your liking. But your second question is really CSS, and not Django related.

Comment: @JohnnyCash - see my edit - let me know if you've got any questions :)

Answer (score 3):

See this too: [Overriding admin css in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357057/overriding-admin-css-in-django)

[image]
http://lincolnloop.com/static/slides/2010-djangocon/customizing-the-admin.html#slide37

Answer (score 3):

@Dominic Rodger is accepted answer. But in this I'm using Inline CSS and override Django base CSS.

**Django Base CSS**

Customize your AdminSite using Django Official Base CSS according to your need.

You can override [Django Official Base CSS](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css)

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px; # change default color
    font-family: "Roboto","Lucida Grande","DejaVu Sans","Bitstream Vera Sans",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff; # Change color
}
```

---

Extend the base_site templates to add extra style to AdminSite.

Create directories and base_site.html.

```
your_project_root_directory/templates/admin/base_site.html
```

**base_site.html**

Copy these into your base_site.html.In style tag you can style your AdminSite

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin') }}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{{ site_header|default:_('Django administration') }}</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %} # Here you can add your CSS

<style>

.module h2, .module caption, .inline-group h2,#header
{   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 5px 3px 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #7CA0C7 url(../img/default-bg.gif) top left repeat-x;
    color: #fff;
}

</style>

{% endblock %}



{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Update: Starting with Django 3.2, Django Admin now supports theming!

You can find information about this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-theming). A list of all variables supported can be found [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css).