# Django 1.10: extend/override admin css

Tags: python, css, django, admin

I want to override the css definition of a select-multiple widget by decreasing the min-height attribute from `contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css`. However, my css is not loaded I think. I use a custom admin form and have defined the Media subclass within this form as well as within the corresponding ModelAdmin:

```
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('/css/admin widgets.css',)
        }
```

The file itself is located in `myapp/static/css/admin widgets.css` and contains:

```
    select[multiple] {
        min-height: 65px;
    }
```

In `settings.py`, I have defined

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "myapp", "static")]
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    STATIC_URL = '/static'
```

I've ran `manage.py collectstatic` which collected all the admin files and my own css file in the project's static-subdir. I've also extended `urls.py` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development), but the widget is still rendered with 150px min-height which is defined in base.css. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I actually use the form within a `django.contrib.admin.TabularInline`. I just also tried to add the Media-subclass to this inline - to no avail.

Comment: This is a long shot, sorry, but I'm not sure you can have spaces in the filename. At least it's something I have never done or seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution myself. It is indeed only one character, but not the whitespace in the filename that Jonas pointed me to (I'm on a Windows filesystem, maybe that's different on linux). Instead, it's the leading slash of the URL in the Media class. Instead of:

```
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('/css/admin widgets.css',)
        }
```

it has to be

```
    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': ('css/admin widgets.css',)
        }
```

or otherwise Django looks directly in the project's root directory for `css/admin widgets.css` instead of the static subdirectory `static/css/admin.widgets.css`.

Furthermore, it seems irrelevant if the Media subclass resides in the Admin, the Inline or the Form directly. It works in any case.

And one more hint: *Always* clear the browser cache before testing when working with css or js. How many times have I already fallen into the same pit? -.-

**EDIT**: There is already an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7357204/3104974) that describes how to override the admin. Old but still correct as of [Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions)