# How to create views where superuser can view and edit other user's passwords in Django?

Tags: django

I'm creating a control panel where the superuser can view a table of all users along with their info. I want to add the users passwords to a column, and a link to an edit form to change the password.

Comment: why not using django admin, do you hate the style?? [CHANGE IT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357057/overriding-admin-css-in-django)!

Comment: Django admin allows to reset password, but it doesn't display it: its just a hash.

Comment: Django only stores the hash. It's not possible to display the original passwords.

Answer (score 0):

let say you have `list_passwords` view where you send super user can view passwords

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@require_http_methods(['GET'])
def list_password(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        # return with error
    else:
        # return data
```

Another view to update password

```
@require_http_methods(['PATCH'])
def update_password(request):
   if not request.user.is_superuser:
       # return with error
   else:
       # update user password
```