# Django Oscar External CSS

Tags: django, django-oscar

I just created a store using Django-Oscar - and I am getting a hard time to add external CSS, I mean, I want to replace the whole default style to a more fancy one with nice futures.
How can I replace them? I've tried their doc, and yet I am not able to replace them.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask].

Comment: It's similar to overriding any other Django library's CSS. You can simply copy paste the oscar's css into your project's (appropriate) static directory and the changes would reflect. This question has answers that tell you how to do it for django-admin, you can expect something very similar for django-oscar - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357057/overriding-admin-css-in-django

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52458971/edit) & include in detail, exactly what you tried, and did not work.