# How to change browse button upload ImageField to drag drop upload on Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Currently I have inline list of photos like this :

[image]

I wish to change the browse button as drag drop upload, does anyone can help to make it ?

Comment: You can already drag & drop a file to the browse button, after which you still need to save the model though. You want the drag & drop to automatically change the file and save the model?

Comment: oh my god, yes right @dirkgroten the feature already exist, thanks for your help. now my question is how to customize the css ? I think now I only need to customize the CSS browse button.

Comment: [overriding admin css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357057/overriding-admin-css-in-django)