# How to change direction of django admin interface?

Tags: django, interface, django-admin

I am making a django application in arabic and I would like the interface to be from right to left. How can I make it happen?

Comment: you can change the css of django admin. get the default css from here: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin

Comment: @zero how to get it in the project

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/37317429/2732913